# 4k screen set to 1920*1080 vs. native 1080p screen. Which one is clearer?

Tags: display, 4k-resolution

There are two screens of the same physical size (say 27 inches). The first one is of native 4k resolution(3840*2160) and the other one is of native 1920*1080.

If I set the first screen to the resolution of 1920*1080. Which screen is clearer?

Since 3840/1920 = 2160/1080 = 2, I think it is pixel perfect（One 1080p pixel can be presented by four 4k pixels）.

Comment: That would depend on the component doing the upscaling. As you already said with that kind resolution it shouldn't really be an issue but it ultimately depends on the upscaler and the kind of display itself.

Comment: There is no good way to answers this. E.g. if I have a poor 3840*2160 monitor and a great 1920x1080 monitor then the great monitor probably looks better, regardless of used resolution. And vice versa. You can assume that both are equal quality, but in practice this is not the case and you will be comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: Having said that, **if** both the 2x2 pixel block and the 1x1 pixel block are the same size I expect little or no quality difference.  That assumes proper upscaling and enough resources to actually process the downscaled 4k.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is continually making a lot of changes in W-10 to make 4K screens display properly.  Many changes were just made in October to accommodate two monitors, where one is a 4k. However, the articles and blogs by the developers at MS can't possibly make all the changes required in everyone's software.  I have a 4k screen set at my recommended 250%, and most everything works and looks great. But some programs must also be changed or they will never look OK.

Make sure you also play with this control: (Control panel: Customize your Display: "Change the size of text, apps, and other items: 250% recommended")

Read and follow the following Windows.com developer blog:
October 24, 2016 - **[High DPI Scaling Improvements for Desktop Applications and “Mixed Mode” DPI Scaling in the Windows 10 Anniversary Update](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/10/24/high-dpi-scaling-improvements-for-desktop-applications-and-mixed-mode-dpi-scaling-in-the-windows-10-anniversary-update/)**